# wpf Select Multiple ListboxItems(i.e, Images) using Keyboard[Ctrl + RightArrow/leftArrow]

Tags: wpf, select, keyboard, listboxitems

I Have grouped the listbox items,i can able to select "Multiple" items by SelectionMode="Extended" or "Multiple". Now i have got two issues and one more thing in "Sorting"

1. When

> [ SelectionMode="Extended"]

i can select Multiple Items by pressing and selecting the items using Mouse, once i move the mouse to the others controls,i'm losing my selection.

2.I'm unable to select Multiple items using Keyboard and unable to travel to listboxItems(i.e,) "Images" using Arrow Keys.

1. I want to sort/Arrange the grouped Items.
   could anybody guide over these..thnx in advance.

   ```
       <CollectionViewSource x:Key="CharacterCollectionView" 
       Source="{Binding}" >
           <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
               <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Name" />
            </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
           <!--<CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
               <cm:SortDescription PropertyName="First" />
           </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>-->
       </CollectionViewSource>

       <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="HorizontalItemsPanel">
           <WrapPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
       </ItemsPanelTemplate>

              <Style x:Key="myListboxStyle">
           <Style.Resources>
               <!-- Background of selected item when focussed -->
               <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
                   <GradientStop Color="#66000000" Offset="0" />
                   <GradientStop Color="#33000000" Offset="1" />
               </LinearGradientBrush>
               <!-- Background of selected item when not focussed -->
               <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
                   <GradientStop Color="#66000000" Offset="0" />
                   <GradientStop Color="#33000000" Offset="1" />
               </LinearGradientBrush>
           </Style.Resources>
       </Style>


   </Window.Resources>

       <DockPanel>
       <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Background="#336699" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
       <ListBox
           Margin="20,20,20,5" DataContext="{Binding}"
           ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CharacterCollectionView}}" 
           DockPanel.Dock="Top" x:Name="MyList" MouseEnter="MyListEvent"
           Width="700" SelectionMode="Extended"    Style="{StaticResource myListboxStyle }"
           Height="700" Background="LightGray" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
           ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" SelectedIndex="1"
           ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"   
           ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel="High"  >

           <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
               <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                   <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                   <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                   <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
                   <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1"/>
                   <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green"/>
                   <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=sizeSlider, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                   <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=sizeSlider, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

                                              <!--<Style.Triggers>
                       <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                           <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
                       </Trigger>
                   </Style.Triggers>-->

               </Style>
           </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

           <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
               <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                   <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="LightSteelBlue"   />
               </ItemsPanelTemplate>
           </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

           <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                   <Viewbox Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
                       <Border BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" DataContext="{Binding}" BorderBrush="IndianRed"   Margin="0" Height="Auto">
                           <DockPanel>
                               <Image
                                   DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                                   Width="150" Margin="5"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                   Height="Auto"  x:Name="Myimage"
                                   Source="{Binding Path=ImageFilepath[0]}"/>
                               <Grid>
                                   <Label Content="{Binding Path=Name[0]}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Normal"   FontSize="13"  />
                               </Grid>
                           </DockPanel>
                       </Border>
                   </Viewbox>
               </DataTemplate>
           </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

                    <ListBox.GroupStyle>
               <GroupStyle>
                   <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                       <DataTemplate>
                           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="18"  Height="Auto" Background="Transparent" FontWeight="Medium"  />
                       </DataTemplate>
                   </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                   <GroupStyle.Panel>
                       <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                           <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"     HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="White"        />
                       </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                   </GroupStyle.Panel>
                       <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>

                           <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                               <Setter Property="Template">
                                   <Setter.Value>
                                       <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                           <GroupBox Header="{Binding Name}" BorderBrush="#336699" BorderThickness="2" Margin="5">
                                               <ItemsPresenter />
                                          </GroupBox>
                                       </ControlTemplate>
                                   </Setter.Value>
                               </Setter>
                           </Style>
                       </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                   </GroupStyle>
              </ListBox.GroupStyle>

           </ListBox>
       <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="2,0,5,5">
           <TextBlock Width="Auto" Text="Min" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14"  Margin="2" Padding="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  />
           <Slider
           Name="sizeSlider"
           Width="300" Orientation="Horizontal"  
           Value="200" Background="PowderBlue"      
           IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"
           Minimum="150" Maximum="250"
           TickPlacement="BottomRight"
           TickFrequency="50"
           AutoToolTipPrecision="10"
           AutoToolTipPlacement="TopLeft"  
           IsDirectionReversed="False"   
           IsMoveToPointEnabled="False" />

               <TextBlock Width="Auto" Text="{Binding Value, ElementName=sizeSlider}" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14"  Margin="2" Padding="0" />
       </StackPanel>
   ```

Comment: As far as I know, in extended mode, travaling is performed by Ctrl+Up/Down keys, and toggling the selection - by ctrl-space. Does this work?

Comment: @AgentFire --In code behind i have handled **KeyUp** for ListBox so that the travelling to the listbox items are **Not** happening, if i don't handle **KeyUp** event , i'm able to travel. Further when toggling selection is not working while handling **KeyUp** event. Andalso i want to auto scroll to set focus to the selected item. Thnx for ur reply.

Comment: @AgentFire Thnx for ur reply now my issues has been solved, Now i stuck up with TabNavigation for Different controls within window.

Comment: @What seems to be the problem?

Comment: @AgentFire Sory for the late reply,i have list box --TabIndex=0 and slider--TabIndex=1,when focus is in Listbox if i give tab focus goes to Slider,this fine,when second time if i give tab focus goes to listbox items,then i give Tab its not moving to **Slider** instead listbox items are getting focus. Could plz help me. Thnx in advance.

Comment: @AgentFire Then i have,say 10 check box items sorted Alphabetically,say for example ,Apple,AirCraft,Ball,Bottom,Cat etc..by pressing **A** through keyboard focus must be set to **Apple** check box,**B** to **Ball** ..